# Get coordinates of scrollview with respect to view over it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

In my `self.view` -subview-> UIScrollview and another `self.view` -subview-> `overlayview`
 which seems over UIScollView

After I zoom the scrollview or pan the scrollview, I want the coordinates of scrollview according to the `overlayview` as shown in image. Where yellow is the `overlayview`

I tried with this code

```
CGRect visibleRect = [scrollView convertRect:scrollView.bounds toView:overlayview];
```

This is not working.

**Need to consider zooming and panning also for scrollview**

How can I achieve relative `coordinate transformation` for two different views?
Or Is there any other way to get that much portion of image from scrollview?

Tried this code but also not working

```
    CGPoint overlayToSelf = [self.view convertPoint:overlayView.frame.origin fromView:overlayView];
   CGPoint selfToScrollview = [scrollView convertPoint:overlayToSelf fromView:self.view];
   visibleRect = CGRectMake(selfToScrollview.x, selfToScrollview.y, Overlaywidth, Overlayheight);
```

[image]

Comment: Try print out `scrollView.bounds`, `overlayview.bounds`, `[scrollView convertRect:scrollView.bounds toView:overlayview]`, `[overlayview convertRect:scrollView.bounds toView:scrollView]`, `[scrollView convertRect:overlayview.bounds toView:overlayview]`, `[overlayview convertRect:overlayview.bounds toView:scrollView]`

Comment: did you solve this problem?